# how can i debug c# application on client system?

Tags: c#, debugging, client-server

i have made an application which runs in network systems.

sometimes it hangs on some computers and it's well on other computers.

i want to debug it and know why this happens on some of them

how could it be possible to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

Add some logging using a logging library, e.g. [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) are both recommended.